# Subtraction inside Collectors.summingInt

Tags: java

I tried to subtract from the EndTime the StartTime in the summingInt(), but it doesn't work, it tells me that "the target type of this expression must be a functional interface".

```
Map<String,Integer> hm = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    hm = listData.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MonitoredData::getActivity,
                    Collectors.summingInt( (MonitoredData::getEndTimeSeconds - 
MonitoredData::getStartTimeSeconds)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Collectors.summingInt` requires a function.

So you have to provide your converter function there.

Replace your `summingInt` with this:

```
Collectors.summingInt(m -> m.getEndTimeSeconds() - m.getStartTimeSeconds())
```